# Consulta que devuelva registros unificados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día, supongamos que tenga estos datos:

```
    c_prove  descri                                   resp      c_sucursal
    -------- ---------------------------------------- --------- ----------
    00000003 3M MEXICO, S.A. DE C.V.                  U         00001
    00000003 3M MEXICO, S.A. DE C.V.                  U         00003
    00000200 PRODUCTOS PRACTICOS DE MADERA SA DE      U         00001
    00000200 PRODUCTOS PRACTICOS DE MADERA SA DE      U         00003
    00000207 JOHNSON & JOHNSON S.A. DE C.V.           U         00001
    00000207 JOHNSON & JOHNSON S.A. DE C.V.           U         00003
```

Deseo hacer un query que me traiga esos mismos datos, pero "agrupados", de tal manera, que si el registro es el mismo, pero con diferente `c_sucursal`, se muestre como registro único, y en el campo `c_sucursal` me muestre ambos códigos de sucursal. algo como esto:

```
        c_prove  descri                                   resp      c_sucursal
        -------- ---------------------------------------- --------- ----------
        00000003 3M MEXICO, S.A. DE C.V.                  U         00001,00003
        00000200 PRODUCTOS PRACTICOS DE MADERA SA DE      U         00001,00003
        00000207 JOHNSON & JOHNSON S.A. DE C.V.           U         00001,00003
```

entiendo que se arregla con un subquery, lo que tengo hasta el momento es esto:

```
select c_prove, descri, resp, (select distinct c_prove, 
           c_sucursal from proveedor where 
           c_sucursal='00001' or c_sucursal='00003') 
from proveedor 
where resp='U'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto normalmente se realiza con la opción `FOR XML PATH` que convierte un resultado en un XML, el cual luego podemos convertir en un string regular.

Aquí dejo el ejemplo con suficientes comentarios que explican cada parte del mismo.

```
SELECT c_prove, 
       descri, 
       resp, 
       STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + c_sucursal --Dejamos la columna sin alias para que no se le asigne ninguna etiqueta
               FROM proveedor i
               WHERE i.c_prove = p.c_prove --Hacemos una consulta relacionada para solo traer las filas correspondientes
               FOR XML PATH('')) --Esta instrucción concatenará todas las filas en formato xml que se convertirá implicitamente en varchar
               , 1, 2, '') --Usamos STUFF para convertir XML en varchar y de paso reemplazar los primeros 2 caracteres por una cadena vacía.
FROM proveedor 
WHERE resp='U'
GROUP BY c_prove, --Usamos GROUP BY en vez de DISTINCT para agrupar antes de concatenar y reducir el procesamiento.
       descri, 
       resp;
```

Comment: ¡Joooo! ¡Qué buena respuesta¡ Gracias bro, que la fuerza os acompañe :D

Answer (score 0):

A partir de `SQL Server 2017` puedes hacer uso de [`STRING_AGG`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

#### Ejemplo

```
SELECT c_prove, descri, resp,
  STRING_AGG(c_sucursal, ',') AS c_sucursal
FROM proveedor 
WHERE resp='U'
GROUP BY c_prove
```